# Destroy messageBox by Timer

Tags: java, gwt, timer, messagebox

I show some messageBox in my program. For example, if i save the data successfully, messageBox shows me "Successfull". But I want to make it close by timer. When it passes two second, it should be closed.I don't need prepared code. It's enough if you tell me the way to do it. My platform is GWT by the way.

Best Regards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be better ways to do this other than Timer. However with timer you would be 
using the GWT's com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer class.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/javadoc/com/google/gwt/examples/TimerExample.java

```
    Timer t = new Timer() {
      public void run() {
        Window.alert("Nifty, eh?");
        // your messageBox code
        t.cancel(); // Since you only need this run once.
      }
    };

    // Schedule the timer to run once in 2 seconds.
    t.schedule(2000);
```

Comment: Thank you my friend but this code is not working for killing the messsagebox. After two second, there is still messagebox on the screen that wait for me to close it :) Actually i'm looking for the answer for closing messagebox.

Comment: Did you invoke messageBox.hide() - i am assuming you are using com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PopupPanel

Comment: Yes, i used but it doesn't work. So i use different way to solve my problem as you say at first time. i create my own messagebox by using panel and i use it in my project. So, it's more flexible from now on.